# Single wsp VS multiple WSPs (100 +)?

Tags: development, solution-package

So we have created Sharepoint 2013 Webparts for a Specific solution. As we didn`t have TFS and had multiple developers work within one install on a remote server , we separated into multiple projects currently 107 + all talking to the same database via a Data Access layer. Thus we have multiple wsp files that we retract and deploy against our Sharepoint site.As it seems a big tasks to collapse this into 1 wsp file , we would like to get a feel if it would be worth the effort ?

WHich one is better and why ?

If a single WSP file solution is best , how would a person go about updating all the name spaces ect in all the 107 projects that live in the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is highly risky and required alot of effort to maintain it. Like multiple developers working in a same farm and they deploy/retract/solutions at the same time(which trigger the IIS) cause alot of issue.

One thing i saw, you can combine all your 100+ wsp into one Solution using **WSPBuilder** and deploy it. check this link for more info: http://ravirapolu.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-combine-multiple-projects-in-one.html

Comment: I went through looking at wspbuilder as there is a work around for making it work in VS2012 and SP2013. But it failed as it cannot do the popup within visual studio, thus a deadend